# Vaadin is unable to create the front end throwing Invalid literal exception

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, vaadin, dispatcher, vaadin-flow

I could not start my vaadin app anymore,
Earlier it builds frontend but after restarting the system it is throwing errors.

The literal "" is something i tried to check in notepad but its some characters which looks like whitespaces.

```
16:43:32.317 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader 
 
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@59689d8d
 _____  _                     ____  ____   __  __   _____         _                 _         _ 
|  ___|| |  ___  __      __  / ___||  _ \ |  \/  | |_   _| _   _ | |_   ___   _ __ (_)  __ _ | |
| |_   | | / _ \ \ \ /\ / / | |    | |_) || |\/| |   | |  | | | || __| / _ \ | '__|| | / _` || |
|  _|  | || (_) | \ V  V /  | |___ |  _ < | |  | |   | |  | |_| || |_ | (_) || |   | || (_| || |
|_|    |_| \___/   \_/\_/    \____||_| \_\|_|  |_|   |_|   \__,_| \__| \___/ |_|   |_| \__,_||_|
                                                                                                

2023-01-19 16:43:33.075  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.application.Application      : Starting Application using Java 11.0.17 on **** with PID 20624 (C:\Users\Downloads\flow-crm-tutorial\flow-crm-tutorial\target\classes started by *** in C:\Users\Downloads\flow-crm-tutorial)
2023-01-19 16:43:33.075  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.application.Application      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-01-19 16:43:33.176  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-01-19 16:43:33.176  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-01-19 16:43:34.492  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-01-19 16:43:34.550  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 34 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-01-19 16:43:35.947  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8081 (http)
2023-01-19 16:43:35.967  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-01-19 16:43:35.967  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.69]
2023-01-19 16:43:36.266  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-01-19 16:43:36.266  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3090 ms
2023-01-19 16:43:36.336  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-01-19 16:43:36.689  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-01-19 16:43:36.710  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:d51f8e85-cbba-4edf-a049-6468c2ed4af8'
2023-01-19 16:43:36.949  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Search for VaadinAppShell took 35 ms
2023-01-19 16:43:38.704  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.VaadinServletContextInitializer  : Search for subclasses and classes with annotations took 1610 ms
2023-01-19 16:43:38.835  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.b.d.startup.DevModeStartupListener   : Starting dev-mode updaters in C:\Users\Downloads\flow-crm-tutorial folder.
2023-01-19 16:43:38.914  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.f.s.FullDependenciesScanner      : Visited 121 classes. Took 49 ms.
Vaadin application has been deployed and started to the context path "/".
2023-01-19 16:43:39.127  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-01-19 16:43:39.226  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.14.Final
2023-01-19 16:43:39.530  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-01-19 16:43:39.762  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2023-01-19 16:43:40.146  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-01-19 16:43:40.154  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-01-19 16:43:40.278  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : Autowired annotation is not supported on static fields: private static org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry com.example.application.KafkaServices.KafkaSpringConsumerService.registry
2023-01-19 16:43:40.435  WARN 20624 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-01-19 16:43:41.120  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-01-19 16:43:41.351  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] c.v.f.s.DefaultDeploymentConfiguration   : 
Vaadin is running in DEVELOPMENT mode - do not use for production deployments.
2023-01-19 16:43:41.452  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8081 (http) with context path ''
2023-01-19 16:43:41.473  INFO 20624 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.application.Application      : Started Application in 9.134 seconds (JVM running for 10.636)
2023-01-19 16:43:43.026  INFO 20624 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-01-19 16:43:43.027  INFO 20624 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-01-19 16:43:43.030  INFO 20624 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 3 ms
2023-01-19 16:43:43.442  WARN 20624 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [311] milliseconds.
2023-01-19 16:43:43.454  INFO 20624 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringInstantiator  : The number of beans implementing 'I18NProvider' is 0. Cannot use Spring beans for I18N, falling back to the default behavior
2023-01-19 16:43:43.466 ERROR 20624 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] c.v.flow.server.DefaultErrorHandler      : 

elemental.json.JsonException: Invalid literal: "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "
    at elemental.json.impl.JsonTokenizer.getValueForLiteral(JsonTokenizer.java:312) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at elemental.json.impl.JsonTokenizer.nextValue(JsonTokenizer.java:177) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at elemental.json.impl.JreJsonFactory.parse(JreJsonFactory.java:64) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at elemental.json.Json.parse(Json.java:53) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.generatePluginFiles(TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.java:94) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.lambda$execute$0(TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.java:64) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.execute(TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.java:62) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:342) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.runNodeTasks(DevModeInitializer.java:435) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.lambda$initDevModeHandler$0(DevModeInitializer.java:348) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.3.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1728) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) ~[na:na]

2023-01-19 16:43:43.468 ERROR 20624 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[springServlet]        : Servlet.service() for servlet [springServlet] threw exception

elemental.json.JsonException: Invalid literal: "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "
    at elemental.json.impl.JsonTokenizer.getValueForLiteral(JsonTokenizer.java:312) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at elemental.json.impl.JsonTokenizer.nextValue(JsonTokenizer.java:177) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at elemental.json.impl.JreJsonFactory.parse(JreJsonFactory.java:64) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at elemental.json.Json.parse(Json.java:53) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.generatePluginFiles(TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.java:94) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.lambda$execute$0(TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.java:64) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.execute(TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.java:62) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:342) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.runNodeTasks(DevModeInitializer.java:435) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.lambda$initDevModeHandler$0(DevModeInitializer.java:348) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.3.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1728) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) ~[na:na]

2023-01-19 16:43:43.472 ERROR 20624 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: elemental.json.JsonException: Invalid literal: "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "] with root cause

elemental.json.JsonException: Invalid literal: "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "
    at elemental.json.impl.JsonTokenizer.getValueForLiteral(JsonTokenizer.java:312) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at elemental.json.impl.JsonTokenizer.nextValue(JsonTokenizer.java:177) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at elemental.json.impl.JreJsonFactory.parse(JreJsonFactory.java:64) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at elemental.json.Json.parse(Json.java:53) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.generatePluginFiles(TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.java:94) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.lambda$execute$0(TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.java:64) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.execute(TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.java:62) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:342) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.runNodeTasks(DevModeInitializer.java:435) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.lambda$initDevModeHandler$0(DevModeInitializer.java:348) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.3.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1728) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) ~[na:na]

2023-01-19 16:43:43.931 ERROR 20624 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] c.v.flow.server.DefaultErrorHandler      : 

elemental.json.JsonException: Invalid literal: "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       "
    at elemental.json.impl.JsonTokenizer.getValueForLiteral(JsonTokenizer.java:312) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at elemental.json.impl.JsonTokenizer.nextValue(JsonTokenizer.java:177) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at elemental.json.impl.JreJsonFactory.parse(JreJsonFactory.java:64) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at elemental.json.Json.parse(Json.java:53) ~[gwt-elemental-2.8.2.vaadin2.jar:2.8.2.vaadin2]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.generatePluginFiles(TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.java:94) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.lambda$execute$0(TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.java:64) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.execute(TaskInstallWebpackPlugins.java:62) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.NodeTasks.execute(NodeTasks.java:342) ~[flow-server-23.3.1.jar:23.3.1]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.runNodeTasks(DevModeInitializer.java:435) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.vaadin.base.devserver.startup.DevModeInitializer.lambda$initDevModeHandler$0(DevModeInitializer.java:348) ~[vaadin-dev-server-23.3.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1728) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183) ~[na:na]
```

The program was running fine and all of a sudden I am getting errors when running the program.

Vaadin version is 23.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no changes were made to the code, can you try a clean build ?

```
mvn vaadin:clean-frontend
mvn clean spring-boot:run
```